# AS3: Necessity of graphics.clear?

Tags: actionscript-3, memory, graphics, draw

I have a function that redraws a Shape every time it gets called

```
function drawIt():void {
  myShape.graphics.clear() //Is this necessary?
  myShape.graphics.beginFill(newColor);
  myShape.graphics.drawRect(0,0,w,h);
  myShape.graphics.endFill();
}
```

If this function gets called often as I tween the color and I don't do the graphics.clear() every time, will I end up with a big stack of rectangles on top of each other that eats up a bunch of memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, take a look on this simple test :

```
var init_memory:uint = System.totalMemory;

var shape:Shape = new Shape();
for(var i:int = 0; i < 1000; i++){
    shape.graphics.clear();
    shape.graphics.beginFill(0xff0000);
    shape.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 10, 10);
    shape.graphics.endFill();
}

trace(System.totalMemory - init_memory);    // gives : 4096 (bytes)
```

let's now comment this line :

```
//shape.graphics.clear();
```

we get :

```
trace(System.totalMemory - init_memory);    // gives : 102400 (bytes)
```

and for just one shape :

```
trace(System.totalMemory - init_memory);    // gives : 4096 (bytes)
```

I think that you didn't need any comment to understand why you should use `graphics.clear()` ...

Hope that can help.

Answer (score 2):

It is necessary or else any new drawing will be added on top of the previous one. If that is not the effect you need then you need to call clear to remove any previous drawing. This behavior can be used to your advantage to crop part of a previous drawing. You could draw a rectangle let's say black, and then draw on top a circle (same color) and the result is a crop.

Bottom line: If you don't call clear all drawing add on top of each other.

Comment: This seems to be the case. If I trace myShape.graphics.readGraphicsData after calling drawIt only once, the output is short. If I trace it after many calls, the output is really long. Although if I do getSize(myShape) before and after, the memory usage doesn't change...

Comment: Drawing commands are math formulas so they require very little amount of memory. On the other hand they require good CPU power to be rendered. Adding the same drawing on top of previous one might not seem to make a difference on the screen and memory wise but quickly lag will take place since CPU will have to work hard to render all those drawings.